# IE link colors in Quirks Mode vs standard

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

Below are two links on where the underline is somewhat blueish and the other is the same color as the text 
[image: Link Colors]

with the following code html 
 `<font color="#003300"> CLX qualifications...</font></a>`

and I'm having trouble replicating how links are rendered in Quirks Mode when I want to render my page in IE standards. This is also happening to my links when, I run my page in firefox as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the font color is overriding the default `a:visited` style.  This CSS should work for your needs:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited {
  color: #003300;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RBg6a/1/) (also you can drop your use of the `font` tag which is alwasy a good thing)

Comment: Thank you, I'm still transitioning an old html styled desin to a more mordern one.